# accessing jmx credentials inside an MBean

Tags: java, jmx

is it possible to access the jmx credentials (one I used to connect to the jconsole) inside the MBean which was invoked as an operation ?

I need this, as I want to do a bulk operation by remote connecting to other servers via jmx and I will need to pass credentials grammatically.

I can add params to the operation itself, but this is not very clean. Also the credentials are visible on the jconolse.

Thanks!

Comment: The usual pattern is that credentials are on a [Subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html#getSubject(java.security.AccessControlContext)) set for the current [AccessControlContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessControlContext.html). I'm not sure if this is the case with MBeans too, but might be worth a shot.